# permutation without using perms command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, permutation

When I have 3 matrices like

```
Matrix1  
A B  
A C  
B D  

Matrix2  
A B  
B C  

Matrix3  
A B  
B C
```

[B C] row is common on Matrix2 and Matrix3 and [A B] row is common on all matrices.
For [B C], I can say [B C 2] and [B C 3]. I can create a mix(permutation) of the rows like [B 2 C 3] and [B 3 C 2].
For [A B], I can say [A B 1], [A B 2], [A B 3]. I also can create a permutation like [A 1 B 2], [A 1 B 3], [A 2 B 1], [A 2 B 3], [A 3 B 1], and [A 3 B 2].

Therefore the results would be

```
A 1 B 2
A 1 B 3  
A 2 B 1
A 2 B 3  
A 3 B 1  
A 3 B 2
B 2 C 3
B 3 C 2
```

Can I get the results without a loop or with only one loop?
perm command or using multiple 'ismember' commands take long time because I need to handle very big size matrices.

Comment: you can always do `edit perms`, see how it works and see if you can do better. It's also don't clear to me how you came up with that example, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: It's not clear how you get from your three matrices to the result. What are the numbers in the result? How are you using the permute command? Please elaborate.

Comment: Thank you for reply and sorry for non-clear explanation. I changed it in more detail. Please let me know if it is still not clear.